# Sharepoint - Client Context when to create and dispose

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am developing a data access layer on top of the sharepoint client model.
I am a bit uncertain when to create and dispose of a client context.
For example I would thinking of create a generic data access component such as:
//this would be a singletonclass
 
PersonDAC: DataAccessBase
public Peron GetItem()
{
... get item using sharepoint client context
}
public Peron UpdateItem(Person)
{
... update using sharepoint client context
}

Should I create the client context in the methods and then dispose it there?
For example, the GetItem would create the context and finally dispose of it (perhps with a 'using' statement)
Or should I create a shared context in the singleton

Any assistance would be greately appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form an SharePoint Admin view would recommend to disposing as quickly has possible when that part is complete.

Using a using() statement should dispose of it when complete, but it was recommended to me once that still should dispose of the connection to make sure...

Search the web for SharePoint dispose I think there is a small tool that can be download to check that solutions are disposing correctly.